# Looking for the value of $\int_{-\infty }^{b} {2(y^2)^a}(e^{2(b-y)}-1)^{-1/2} \, dy$

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm trying to calculate the following definite integral

$$\int_{-\infty }^{b} \frac{2(y^2)^a}{\sqrt{e^{2(b-y)}-1}} \, dy=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\left(\left(b-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2\right)^a}{\sqrt{e^y-1}}$$

with $a>0$ and $0\leq b<1$.

*Wolfram Mathematica* don't give me the result. I wonder if  it will be solved using complex analysis (contour integral).

Any help will be wellcome.

Comment: I have just corrected the statement. I had tried to be simple in the question but that is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, you are asking for analytical solutions to integrals of the form

$$I_n(\mu) \equiv \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{(x-\mu)^n}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}\,\mathrm dx$$

But rather than consider $\mu\in[0,2), n\in\mathbb R^+$, $\mu$ can be treated as any number in $\mathbb R$ without affecting convergence, and for my own convenience I will restrict $n$ to the nonnegative integers $\mathbb Z^*$.

---

Now, if $\mu\neq0$ we can expand out the numerator in terms of the binomial theorem to find that

$$I_n(\mu)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k}\mu^{n-k}I_k(0) \tag1$$

and so instead of evaluating $I_n(\mu)$ for $\mu\in\mathbb R$, it is sufficient to only evaluate those cases where $\mu=0$ and utilize $(1)$. Therefore, let us define and seek solutions to

$$I_n \equiv I_n(0)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}\,\mathrm dx$$

To do so, define a generating function

$$\begin{align}
F(z) &\equiv \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty I_n\frac{z^n}{n!}
\\ &= \int\limits_0^\infty \left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n z^n}{n!}\right) \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}
\\ &= \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{xz}}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$

And by making the substitution $e^x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-t}$, we see that the integral can be expressed in terms of the beta function as

$$F(z) = \operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-z\right) \tag2$$

And since by definition of the functional equation,

$$I_n = F^{(n)}(0)$$

we have reduced the task of solving the integrals in question to computing partial derivatives of the beta function and evaluating at $z=0$.

---

As an example, let us evaluate $I_2(\pi)$. First we utilize $(1)$ to find that

$$\begin{align}
I_2(\pi) &= 1\cdot\pi^2 I_0(0) - 2\cdot\pi^1 I_1(0) + 1\cdot\pi^0 I_2(0)
\\ &= \pi^2I_0 - 2\pi I_1 + I_2
\end{align}$$

Now, we utilize $(2)$ to evaluate the remaining integrals.

Trivially,

$$I_0=\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\pi$$

For $I_1$, we will need to first find

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-z\right)$$

which we can determine by writing the beta function in terms of the gamma function and applying derivative rules as normal. Then by using [Gauss's Digamma Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssDigammaTheorem.html) we can evaluate at $z=0$ to conclude that

$$I_1 = 2\pi\ln(2)$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $z$ a second time, evaluating at $z=0$, and simplifying the resulting polygamma functions, we can similarly conclude that

$$I_2 = \frac{\pi^3}{3}+4\pi\ln^2(2)$$

and finally, plugging these values back in, we find that

$$I_2(\pi) = \frac{4\pi^3}{3}-4\pi^2\ln(2)+4\pi\ln^2(2)$$

Comment: It's a good approach, though didn't the author ask for a solution for any arbitrary $a\geq0$ and not just integers?

Comment: Splendid. What a pity that the question is put on hold.

Comment: Many thanks, Ben Colson, is a good advance. As Diger says, parameter $a$ is a non negative real number.

Comment: I know that the question called for real exponent values, not just integers, and I commented on that briefly in my answer, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find such a solution. But I think that even to extend the solutions to accommodate fractional exponents would require an entirely novel approach that unfortunately I haven't yet discovered.